# After installing SQL Server 2019 CU2, SQL Server Agent stops working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, cumulative-update

After installing SQL Server 2019 CU2, SQL Server Agent starts consuming too much CPU resulting into skip job schedules.

Although the agent service is running but it looks like hang and didn't process / kick off any jobs.

Once I re-start the Agent service it starts working again (cpu = 0), but then again after some time 1-2 hours CPU intake in high and jobs do not run.

Is anybody else facing same issue with SQL Server 2019 CU2?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Same thread is here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260190/sql-server-agent-fails-after-installing-sql-server-2019-cu2

Comment: Maybe this tweet can help: https://twitter.com/mandrea09/status/1231043223826632704 "That happened on two of my servers that I patched with. One of issues was with the master dB master key. Something along the lines of not being able to decrypt it. Modified it and ended up turning on trace flag 902 to get it started and repaired it and is working fine."